# Android PopupMenu behaviour on activity recreation

Tags: android, view

I use a conditional popup menu

```
if (smth) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
    popup.getMenu().add("Do it").setOnMenuItemClickListener(<work with views>);
    popup.show();
}
```

On activity recreation popup menu still visible, but all references to views inside click listener refers to old views, so it causes crashes und unexpected behaviour sometimes.
Do you know the best approach of working with popup menus? Or, can i disable popup menus recreation?

UPD
It seems popup recreation only happens on crecreation while entering multiscreen (strange behaviour).
And of course, i can dismiss popups in onDestroy, but it's not very cool to keeps every popup reference in activity or fragment. Hope you know a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should dismiss the popup menu in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`. If you do this, then you can either recreate it or not when your activity is recreated depending upon your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's really very unconvenient. Hope the easier way exists.